# Can you fix the false negative rate in a classifier in scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using a [Random Forest classifer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) in scikit learn with an imbalanced data set of two classes. I am much more worried about false negatives than  false positives.  Is it possible to fix the false negative rate (to, say, 1%) and ask scikit to optimize the false positive rate somehow?

If this classifier doesn't support it, is there another classifier that  does?

Comment: You may be able to use the `predict_proba` method of the classifier to set your own discrimination threshold.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the problem of **class imbalance** in sklearn can be partially resolved by using the `class_weight` parameter.

this parameter is either a dictionary,  where each class is assigned a uniform weight, or is a string that tells sklearn how to build this dictionary. For instance, setting this parameter to 'auto', will weight each class  in proportion of the inverse of its frequency.

By weighting the class that is less present with a higher amount, you can end up with 'better' results.

Classifier like like **SVM** or **logistic regression** also offer this `class_weight` parameter.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26244744/2526441) Stack Overflow answer gives some other ideas on how to handle class imbalance, like under sampling and oversampling.

Comment: RandomForestClassifier also has class_weight in master (and will have it in the release version in a week or so).

Comment: @AndreasMueller Thank you. If I really only care about a fixed false negative weight, does it make sense to specify as the loss function the false positive weight and try to optimize using one of the classifier that supports user defined loss functions?

Comment: @AndreasMueller One other thing. The 0.16.1 documentation claims that RandomForestClassifier has class_weight  . Is this not functional currently?

Comment: It should be working. There are not models with user defined loss functions. You can select hyper-parameter based on user defined scorers, though.

Answer (score 4):

I found this article on class imbalance problem.

> http://www.chioka.in/class-imbalance-problem/

It has basically discussed the following possible solutions to summarize:

- Cost function based approaches
- Sampling based approaches
- SMOTE (Synthetic Minority Over-Sampling Technique)
- recent approaches : RUSBoost, SMOTEBagging and Underbagging

Hope It may help.

Answer (score 1):

Random forests is already a bagged classifier so that should already give some good results.

One typical way of getting desired False positive or False negative accuracies is to analyze it using ROC curves
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_roc.html
and modifying certain parameters to achieve the desired FP rates for example.

Not sure whether it would be possible to tune the random forest classifier FP rates using parameters. You can look at other classifiers based on your application.